# Will closing the browser prevent a PHP script from finishing execution?

Tags: php, html, apache

If an ajax request is made to server to run a script in backend and user closed the browser. Will that script complete execution on backend if it started and was in midprocess?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NO..**, PHP script will not terminate its execution.

**YES..** it'll complete its execution.

Once php script is initiated, it'll complete its execution and then will stop.

because, php runs at server side, it can't be interrupted by client side simple event like `browser window close`.

But however client will not be able to see the output.

for ex:

Try This Code:

```
//File Name: xyz.php
<?php
$fp=fopen("output.txt","w");
$count=0;
for($count=0;1;$count++){
  //Infinite loop
  fwrite($fp,"".PHP_EOL."".$count."");
  sleep(1);
  if ($count>=60) break;
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

and now test this file, Even after you close the browser window, it'll continue to print inside that output file (`output.txt`).

Comment: Actually YES, he asked if the script will complete it's execution :D

Comment: What about the ignore_user_abort option? I think it's set to false by default in most PHP installations. Does the browser not send abort on browser/tab close? What if the user hits the stop button instead?

Comment: @RaisinBranCrunch, Why don't you try it and let me know? Actually I'm not working in `php` from last 4 years. so not aware of these new features. However, if you can try and let me know it'll be really helpful.

Comment: @VedantTerkar Tested with Chrome & Firefox, the stop button doesn't trigger abort either, even if the ignore_user_abort option is set to false. Interesting.

Comment: @RaisinBranCrunch, I believe that option is only honed if `php` script is running from the terminal; In that case if you close the terminal, the script will stop its execution. At least that's what I can understand from the documentation. so for browser, that option should not affect.

Answer (score 2):

Well, PHP is server side, it computes all the code and then sends the results to the client. So I guess it finishes the script execution even if you close the browser.