# PHP execution stops after closing browser tab

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

My site runs on nginx and PHP7.4 fpm. I have coded a backend script that can be called from the browser. For debug purpose I put quite a few error_log statements in the code.

I found that if I do any of the following the script will stop running - no error_log output.

1. close browser tab
2. press ESC
3. cloudflare reaches timeout

It's almost immediate that any of the above events occure, output in the error log stops.

I tried putting ignore_user_abort(true) at the top of my script, didn't help.

What could be causing this? Shouldn't PHP script keep running till completion regardless of browser activity?

Comment: You press `ESC` anywhere? E.g. on desktop and it terminates request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will closing the browser prevent a PHP script from finishing execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682956/will-closing-the-browser-prevent-a-php-script-from-finishing-execution)

Comment: @Justinas Browser tab. 

Nope, it does not answer my question and my question does not duplicate with that question.

Comment: Check your [ignore_user_abort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) setup.

Comment: I suspect it depends entirely on the server API and the set of intermediate proxies and stuff. In any case, I don't think this is a set up to be relied on. Long running processes like this are best implemented with a queue system of some kind and a server-side consumer.